# Blank Preferences on Arduino IDE 2.0.1

Tags: arduino-ide-2

I just install this new IDE on my pc.
Yesterday, I changed my sketch folder location on preferences.
And when i need to change it again, the preferences shown nothing. Ive restart my pc and its not working.
How to solve this? Should I reinstall this app?
[image]

Comment: I just reinstall the app. But the preferences still blank.

Comment: Run the IDE from a command-line.  If any relevant error or warning messages show up, edit them into the question.

Comment: I checked the [Arduino IDE issue list](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+preferences) and did not find anything about a blank preferences dialog. Seems like the best way forward would be to open an issue there. Until then, it may be that deleting the arduino preferences folders/files somewhere in your user home suffices (probably C:\Users\Meiko\.arduino or some subfolder in C:\Users\Meiko\AppData in your case, I'm not on windows). -- Actually, don't delete, move it away so you can include it in a bug report later.

Comment: try to provide more info into this thread on arduino forum. it is a discussion with a member of Arduino Team. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/blank-file-settings-menu-in-arduino-ide-2-0-1/1048087